# Enable true color for neovim in Fedora 25

Tags: fedora, colors, gnome-terminal, nvim

I use neovim in tmux in gnome-terminal on Fedora 25. [Here](http://homeonrails.com/2016/05/truecolor-in-gnome-terminal-tmux-and-neovim/) I found out, that I do not have true color support because terminal is not linked to some *libvte* of correct version. Since many nvim color schemes need true color support (and also I want this from a general perspective) I'd like to activate it!

However, the posted site only refers to the ppa (which as I imagine are ubuntu-repos). So my question: **How do I activate true colors in gnome-terminal on fedora 25?**

Comment: If you downvote, please at least comment, what can be improved in the question. I've serached high and low and did not find anything on the topic (except for Ubuntu SE and other ubuntu only solutions) so this should be no reason.

Comment: You need to make better research before ask.

Comment: Nearly every question here can be answered by some page on the web or some docu etc. However, most of the time people who ask just do not stumble across their perfect result just so... But thanks for the positive attitude!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those instructions do not actually provide the correct test for the version of libvte used on Fedora, since our `gnome-terminal-server` is in `/usr/libexec`. Instead, I'd suggest

```
$ rpm -qR gnome-terminal|grep vte
libvte-2.91.so.0()(64bit)
vte291(x86-64) >= 0.46.0
```

Here, we see that 0.46.0 is greater than the 0.36 your tutorial says is required, so ***this is not your problem***. In fact, check this out:

```
$ echo $COLORTERM
truecolor
```

**TrueColor is already enabled *out of the box* on Fedora 25 Workstation.**

`$COLORTERM` is also `truecolor` *inside* of tmux. In fact, [this blog post](https://deductivelabs.com/en/2016/03/using-true-color-vim-tmux/) has a simple [test script](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jakob-lundberg/65bed87d584df7bd5ed7/raw/37fb1314b1c468033c1fb78a762de3f83ee758fa/test_24bit.sh) with which I verified that TrueColor is in fact working both outside and inside tmux with no further configuration.

So, this is down to neovim configuration. To make it work in current versions, you need `set termguicolors` in your `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`. (In versions before May 2016, set the environment variable `NVIM_TUI_ENABLE_TRUE_COLOR` to `1`.) This is documented in the [neovim log of "breaking changes"](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Following-HEAD#20160511).

Comment: Thanks! The blog post was actually the fix. It happend to be the setup of neovim, which I did not have set up. Thank you!

Comment: Aha! `NVIM_TUI_ENABLE_TRUE_COLOR=1`. Glad I could help.

Comment: actually Jakob Lundberg pointed out, that this variable is unused now, since [this patch](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/4690). The new statement is: `if has(“termguicolors”)
set termguicolors
endif`